# Firebase v3 - How to Reinitialize Default App?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I modify the `initializeApp` config object parameters via scripting how could I reinitialize the app to use the new values?

The only way it works now is to reload/refresh the page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can delete and then reinitialize the the app with

```
firebase.app().delete().then(function() {
  firebase.initializeApp(myNewConfig);
});
```

Alternatively, you can keep the old app around and initialize a new app with a different name:

```
firebase.initializeApp(myConfig1);
firebase.initializeApp(myConfig2, 'myOtherApp');

var db1 = firebase.database();
var db2 = firebase.app('myOtherApp').database();
```

Comment: Thanks!  I would like to know how you figured this out?  Did you find this in documentation?

Comment: Thanks! You save me :)

Comment: Can I delete an specific app by using name? 
If I want to delete "myOtherApp", so how can I delete it?

Comment: firebase.app('myOtherApp').delete().then(/*...*/);

Comment: This doesn't work for the default app because the value for "deleted" is set to true and never changes back so things like remote config won't work

Answer (score 0):

After delete Firebase.app and set new initializeApp still Push notification from old initializeApp and new one  "flutter".

My Code:

```
 FirebaseApp secondaryApp = Firebase.app(name);
 await secondaryApp.delete();


 await Firebase.initializeApp(
   name: name,
   options: FirebaseOptions(
     apiKey: apiKey,
     appId: appId,
     messagingSenderId: messagingSenderId,
     projectId: projectId,
   ));
```