# firebase.initializeApp() does not reestablish a connection to onAuthStateChanged

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have three firebase instances: dev, staging and prod.
My application needs to authenticate the user with an email and password.
At login time my application has no idea if the user is in the dev, staging or prod databases.

So I decided to loop over my different config files and attempt to login to each database one-by-one.  The logic in pseudocode looks like this:

```
    var success = reinitializeFirebaseAndLogin(prodConfig, email, password);
    if (!success) {
        success = reinitializeFirebaseAndLogin(stagingConfig, email, password);
        if (!success) {
            success = reinitializeFirebaseAndLogin(devConfig, email, password);
            if (!success) {
                display("Login Failed.");
            }
        }
    }

    function reinitializeFirebaseAndLogin(config, email, password) {
        reinitializeDefaultFirebase(config);
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);  //if successful, onAuthStateChanged() should be called.
    }

    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582860/firebase-v3-how-to-reinitialize-default-app
    function reinitializeDefaultFirebase(config) {
        firebase.app().delete().then(function() {
            firebase.initializeApp(config);
        });
    }
```

The problem is once the reinitializeDefaultFirebase() method is called then onAuthStateChanged is no longer called.
It seems that the firebase.app().delete() loses the connection to firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged().

So the questions become:

1. How do I reestablish the connection to `onAuthStateChanged`?
2. Is this logic correct or is there a better way?
3. Should `firebase.initializeApp()` reestablish a connection to `onAuthStateChanged` without any special coding on my side?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is not a good design and is not efficient. firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword is asynchronous. It returns a promise that rejects with an error. In your case, if(success) will always be true even when the sign in fails. The promise returned could reject with an error that the user does not exist, or invalid password. It doesn't necessarily mean this would work in your other configuration.

Comment: That seems like a great *answer* @bojeil. :-)

Comment: You are correct, if the above pseudocode were run then it would fail.  Sorry for the confusing pseudocode.  I meant to convey if the method reinitializeFirebaseAndLogin fails then attempt to login to another database.  Nevertheless, the question remains, how do I reestablish a connection to firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged after the firebase.app().delete() is called?